# Матрицы в Python

Tags: python-3.x

Есть вот такое задание: Дана действительная квадратная матрица порядка N (N — нечетное), все элементы которой различны. Найти наибольший элемент среди стоящих на главной и побочной
диагоналях и поменять его местами с элементом, стоящим на пересечении этих диагоналей.
У меня получилось все, кроме части, где нужно поменять элементы местами. Прошу помочь, если не трудно.
Код:

````
if N%2==0:
    print('Ошибка')
else:
    a=[]
    for i in range(N):
        b=[]
        for j in range(N):
            print('Введите [',i,',',j,'] элемент:(числа не должны повторяться) ')
            b.append(int(input()))
        a.append(b)
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            print(a[i][j],end=' ')
        print()
    print()
    c=[]
    d=[]
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            if i==j:
                c.append(a[i][j])
            if j==(N-(i+1)):
                d.append(a[i][j])
    print(c)
    print(d)
    for elem1 in c:
        for elem2 in d:
            if elem1==elem2:
                print('Число на пересечении диагоналей: ', elem1)
    m1=max(c)
    m2=max(d)
    if m1>m2:
        max=m1
    if m2>m1:
        max=m2
    print('Наибольшее число =', max)
    print() ```
````

Comment: вы можете из матрицы ```a``` сразу взять центральный элемент, для определения его индекса просто поделите заданное число *N* на 2 и округлите в большую сторону. из матрицы его достать так: ```a[k][k]``` , где k - найденный индекс

Comment: пересмотрите логику своей программы, вам не надо создавать новые массивы для сбора всех элементов диагоналей, потому что в таком случае для каждого из них еще придется запоминать их индекс в основной матрице. Вам нужно просто пробегаться по диагонали и искать наибольший элемен --> (пример для главной диагонали) в начале программы наибольшим принимаете первый элемент диагонали, дальше ходите по диагонали и сравниваете элементы с этим наибольшим, если есть элемент который больше то запоминаете его и его индекс

Comment: @Nobody, а разве не надо округлять в меньшую сторону? Индекс же начинается с 0.

Comment: хорошо, попробую
Спасибо!

Comment: @DanBear, вы правы, надо в меньшую